# Double exit in gzexe

Tags: shell-script, sh

I have seen in [gzexe](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gzexe) [(source)](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/gnuzip/gnuzip-31/gzip/gzexe.in) they use the following pattern used in a lot of places all over the file:

```
(exit $res); exit $res
```

What purpose does the `exit` inside the sub-shell? Doesn't seem to do anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

It works the same way as `return` in a function or sourced shell script.

```
# EXIT
$ echo $(exit 12) $?
>>> 12

# FUNCTION
func() {
    return 12
}

$ echo $(func) $?
>>> 12

# More simple
echo `return 12` $?
>>> 12
```

Where `$?` is exit code of the last performed action.

Comment: I see `(exit $res)` is setting the return code to `$res`, but `exit $res` does it also, and it *does* terminate the script. I don't see why put both together...

Comment: It is senseless to be doing it. I deleted all `(exit $res); ` from source code and got the same result.